# Escape quotes in java spring request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a Java Spring controller.
I want to escape all quotes in my request (sanitize it for using it in SQL queries for example).

Is there a way to do that with Spring ?

Example :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<String[]> myEndpoint(@RequestBody Map<String, String> params, @AuthenticationPrincipal Account connectedUser) throws Exception{
    return myService.runQuery(params, connectedUser);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code of `runQuery` ?

Comment: I would like to sanitize the `params` variable (escape quotes) in the controller if possible

Comment: If you just want to validate your  request parameters, why not using custom validators??

Comment: Let's say I don't know the code of the service, as I'm only in charge of the controller. @Afridi could you provide an example ?

Comment: @matthiasbe check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate all your request parameters in controllers, you can use custom validators. For Complete info, check [Complete Example](http://www.bbenson.co/post/spring-validations-with-examples/)

Brief Overview:

### Validator Implementation

```
@Component
public class YourValidator implements Validator {

@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(YourPojoType.class);
}

@Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if (target instanceof YourPojoType) {
           YourPojoType req = (YourPojoType) target;
           Map<String, String> params = req.getParams();
           //Do your validations.
           //if any validation failed, 
           errors.rejectValue("yourFieldName", "YourCustomErrorCode", "YourCustomErrorMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
@RestController
public class YourController{

   @Autowired
   private YourValidator validator;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public List<String[]> myEndpoint(@Valid YourPojoType req, BindingResult result, @AuthenticationPrincipal Account connectedUser) throws Exception{

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       //throw exception
    }
    return myService.runQuery(params, connectedUser);
} 

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

}